# SQL Server 2008: How to see which option is SET for a database level

Tags: sql-server-2008, settings

I need to know a value of options ANSI_NULLS and QUOTENT_IDENTIFIER on database level.

Which SQL statement may I use in order to see whether they are ON or OFF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Care of [here](http://dbalink.wordpress.com/2009/05/03/checking-sql-server-database-option-settings-quickie-again/) you can use the following to retrieve options are that on.

`EXEC sp_dboption TestDB`

Answer (score 0):

[sp_dboption](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933268%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) will retrieve the data you want, but it's deprecated and no longer available in SQL 2012. Instead you should use [`sys.databases`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) view, e.g.

```
select  is_ansi_null_default_on
    ,   is_ansi_nulls_on
    ,   is_quoted_identifier_on
from sys.databases where name = db_name()
```